# Bluez 5.48 - How to force the Bluetooth transport state from active to idle - embedded sink end

Tags: linux, bluetooth, embedded, dbus, bluez

I have the usual situation where iOS applications are not providing pause and play signals to the sink via AVRCP DBus signalling. Android is fine. The only indication of a paused stream on many iOS apps ( if still maximised ) is the transport state will go idle after some time. If the user toggles between pause and play there's no way of knowing this sink end ( i.e. embedded speaker ) apart from actual audio. Android will signal pause and play over AVRCP on the apps I've tested. On iOS once the transport is idle a "play" will immediately place the transport back into an active state. So... Is there a way, Bash, Python, C or whatever that I can force the **transport** of a connected device ( i.e. iPad ) from **active=>idle** from the embedded sink side? If it were possible I would then know whenever "play" is pressed making the transport active again. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In short, you need to listen to `PropertiesChanged` signal on `org.bluez.MediaTransport1` interface and parse the signal for state change.

You can register to Bluez DBUS interface as below during initialization.

```
g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe(conn, "org.bluez", "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
                "PropertiesChanged", NULL, "org.bluez.MediaTransport1", G_DBUS_SIGNAL_FLAGS_NONE,
                bluez_signal_transport_changed, NULL, NULL);
```

Below sample is the functionality which parses for state change signal,

```
static void bluez_signal_transport_changed(GDBusConnection *conn, const gchar *sender,
        const gchar *path, const gchar *interface, const gchar *signal, GVariant *params,
        void *userdata) {
    (void)conn;
    (void)sender;
    (void)interface;
    (void)userdata;

    const gchar *signature = g_variant_get_type_string(params);
    GVariantIter *properties = NULL;
    GVariantIter *unknown = NULL;
    GVariant *value = NULL;
    struct ba_transport *t;
    const char *iface;
    const char *key;

    if (strcmp(signature, "(sa{sv}as)") != 0) {
        error("Invalid signature for %s: %s != %s", signal, signature, "(sa{sv}as)");
        goto fail;
    }    

    g_variant_get(params, "(&sa{sv}as)", &iface, &properties, &unknown);
    debug("Signal: %s: %s", signal, iface);

    while (g_variant_iter_next(properties, "{&sv}", &key, &value)) {

        if (strcmp(key, "State") == 0) {

            if (!g_variant_is_of_type(value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_STRING)) {
                error("Invalid argument type for %s: %s != %s", key,
                        g_variant_get_type_string(value), "s");
                goto fail;
            }

             printf("state is %s\n", g_variant_get_string(value, NULL));  
        }

        g_variant_unref(value);
        value = NULL;
    }

fail:
    if (properties != NULL)
        g_variant_iter_free(properties);
    if (value != NULL)
        g_variant_unref(value);
}
```

Where `g_variant_get_string(value, NULL))` will provide you the current state and you decide the SINK operation based on the current state.

Comment: Thanks, I can already easily monitor the MediaTransport state. I want to force the transport state to idle, that's all!

Comment: @edtrx850 AFAIK you can't force that manually. As in here, https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/media-api.txt#n586 `state` is readonly property. Only way is to inform the bluez sink end is by pausing the audio in source end. Underlying stack changes the state automatically. There is no way to force this!

Comment: Figured that! Real pain with some iOS apps not spitting out AVRCP play / pause signals I have no way of knowing if it's steaming or not. The reason why I need to know is for convenience switching to pinch the sink; however I also need to know when Bluetooth wants it back! Hence the need to detect play. System cannot use mixers either for the sink, needs to be raw as possible. Wonder if I could hack Bluez somewhere to force the transport to go idle?

Comment: @edtrx850: I don't prefer tweaking bluez for this. In short, state change is reported by the remote devices `org.bluez.MediaTransport1` interface. So bluez in controlled end is just the listener. If you still want to tweak it, you need to check the callbacks in `org.bluez.MediaTransport1` defined in https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/profiles/audio/transport.c#n105 this gets implementation here https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/profiles/audio/transport.c#n105

Comment: I certainly don't prefer tweaking it either! But it's worth a shot, I was perusing those links you sent last night in fact, so that's reassuring in a way. Be so much  easier if the iOS YouTube coders just implemented the full AVRCP suite. Anyway thanks for you input - appreciated!

Comment: @edtrx850 Good luck!